# Update Opportunity close date based on Case stage

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement wherein Opportunity close date needs to be updated when 'stage' on related case is 'Closed'.

Comment: That's great! What is your question? What have you tried so far? Is it possible to have more than one `Case` related to an `Opportunity` (if so, what should happen then? Should any case being closed advance the stage? do all of them need to be closed?)

Comment: There is no direct relationship from 'Case' to 'Opportunity' rather it is that 'Cases' are hooked up at the 'Account' level. So, yes you are right in pointing me out which 'Opportunity' records are to be updated when a 'Case' record gets updated and I thank you for nudging me on it.